# Can the Personalization checkbox be set to checked by default?

Tags: exm

In EXM under delivery tab there is a Personalization checkbox. Can it be set to checked by default? This is on a 9.0.2 installation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please double check that you really want to do this since this is meant for a specific purpose.
However, you can do this:

1. Go to /sitecore/templates/Email Campaign/Messages/Mail
   Message/__Standard Values
2. Check the "**This email uses personalisation**" Checkbox.

Since, this is a shared field so no matter what language you use for the Email campaign, it will always be checked.

[image]

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please mark this as an answer if it solved what your are trying to acheive.

Comment: In 9.0.2 the location is /sitecore/templates/System/Email/Messages/Mail Message/__Standard Values